# Auto Forwarding Gmails in label does not forward complete conversation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a time-based trigger set up in a GAS that automatically forwards emails every night based on being in the label "Approved" and then moves it to a different label.

Here is the code:

```
function autoForwardApprovedEmails() {
var getLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Approved');
var setLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SentToIssueTrack');
var recipient = 'jungleescapehabarana@gmail.com';

var threads = getLabel.getThreads();
var forwarded = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages()[i];

if (messages != undefined){
   messages.forward(recipient);
   forwarded++;

   thread.addLabel(setLabel);
   thread.removeLabel(getLabel);
   }
 }

}
```

The code works totally fine however there is one problem. The email consists of two mails, one which is a request including an excel attachment and the other one the response email approved. My problem is that it only forwards the mail with attachment and not the response that is approved. I need it to forward both in one time though. You can see here a screenshot of the emails needed to be forwarded together: 
[image]

Here, only the first email forwards. I cannot figure out why it doesnt forward the complete thread. Would be great if somebody can help me.

Comment: In your 'for' loop, you are looping over threads but NOT over messages. Calling threads[i].getMessages() will return an array of Gmail messages that you need to loop over in a separate 'for' loop. Currently, you extract only the i-nth message from the array.

Comment: ah I see. I changed and it works now. Thank you.